# TBS - Query SQL with the new version of TBS using native sql class

Tags: php, mysql, sql, tinybutstrong

I'm writing here regarding the use of the `SQL` `TBS` plugin. 
I went through the www.tinybutstrong.com web site, guide, forum, etc., but can't figure out the answer.

I used to use the plugin `tbssql_mysql.php`, but it became obsolete with `PHP7`.
I went on the `TBS` site to get the new version but realised it was now native with `TBS`, and wasn't a separate module anymore.

But then, I realised I have actually no idea on how to create a new `SQL` object and perform queries like I used to.
Ie, I used to do this:

```
include_once('tbssql_mysql.php');
$Db_dev = new clsTbsSQL();
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$Db_dev->Connect('localhost:3306',$user,$pass,'ecv');
$query1     = 'SELECT id, page FROM page_menu ORDER BY ordre ASC';
$get_menu   = $Db_dev->GetRows($query1);
```

But I have no idea how to do all of this with this new `TBS` version.
Could you point me to the documentation regarding connecting to a `DB` and querying with `TBS` now?

Kind regards.

Comment: the PHP extension MySQLi is available for PHP 7, if you have it you can use the TBS plugin `tbssql_mysqli.php` instead of `tbssql_mysql.php`